# JavaScript Não executa .click corretamente com JSF

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, xhtml

O script funciona parcialmente, ele atualiza a pagina após 5 sec., no entanto não executa o click no botão:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        cache_clear()
      }, 5000);
});

function cache_clear() {
    document.getElementById('listTab:teste').click();
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Meu form (.xhtml):

```
<h:form id="listTab">
  <p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Atualizar Tabela" class="btn btn-block btn-success" ajax="false" actionListener="#{chamadoBean.teste()}" id="teste"/>
  </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Meu Bean:

```
public void teste() {
   System.out.println("teste");
}
```

Não mostra nada no console após a pagina atualizar, sendo assim, o botão não é clicado. Alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, consegui resolver utilizando socket.

```
<o:socket channel="clock" onmessage="socketListener" >
   <f:ajax event="someEvent" listener="#{chamadoBean.listaChamado()}" render=":tblLista" />
</o:socket>
```